# ASP.NET Gridview scrolling up on selecting a row that is near the bottom - How to stop it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, datagridview

I have a asp.net gridview that contains more than 100 rows. When I scroll down and select a row, the grid refreshes and automatically scrolls up to the first row. However, I can see the selected row in the colour I want when I scroll down. But the requirement is, it shouldn't scroll up automatically when I select a row. How do you prevent the gridview from scrolling up upon selecting the row.

I think we have some logic to refresh/databind on selected index change or selected row change.

EDIT:

My grid is inside an update panel.

Comment: How are you selecting a row?

Comment: @artm: Just clicking on a row by scrolling down. I also tried MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" its not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this in isolation, but this is the code I'm using to achieve something similar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        yPos = $get('<%= UpdatePanel3.ClientID %>').children[2].scrollTop;
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $get('<%= UpdatePanel3.ClientID %>').children[2].scrollTop = yPos;
    }
</script>
```